# unable to compile Apache flink dependency in android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

dependencies in Module `build.gradle` are

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.11:1.4.0'


}
```

but whenever I compile the code it gave me the following error

```
   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK reference.conf    File1: /Users/amar/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11/2.4.20/251b1d970698b81dad5aa8b84eec3eea835259d2/akka-actor_2.11-2.4.20.jar  File2: /Users/amar/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.flink/flink-runtime_2.11/1.4.0/c55676f3ca4c7edd82374659471e98b2384868a8/flink-runtime_2.11-1.4.0.jar   File3: /Users/amar/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe.akka/akka-stream_2.11/2.4.20/7545a4f86cbb372c337dbdb2846110df86a8cc70/akka-stream_2.11-2.4.20.jar    File4: /Users/amar/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe/ssl-config-core_2.11/0.2.1/3d2e6a36a7427d6f9d3921c91d6ac1f57dc47b57/ssl-config-core_2.11-0.2.1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by following these steps

**step # 1** using the dependency from [https://mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-java) instead of [https://search.maven.org](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.flink%7Cflink-streaming-java_2.11%7C1.4.0%7Cjar).

**step # 2** Also, I found out that as these files are large which crosses the limit of 64K classes that can be included in DEX files, so I have to configure for Multidex details of which are given [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

**step # 3** most of the issue was being created by `Jacktoolchain`, so we can disable that and replace it with `retro-lambda` for which you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrolambda/article.html). Make sure to disable `Jacktoolchain` by commenting or deleting as shown below

```
//        jackOptions { enabled true }

//        dexOptions { incremental true }
```

**step # 4** Exclude these packages from `packagingOptions` as shown below

```
packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'


    }
```

**step # 5** You may find it weird, but this hack works like

```
 compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'link-java', version: '1.4.0'
```

was not working and was giving some error, but it worked when compile is replaced by provided. I don't know why, please let me know if you know

```
  provided group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-java', version: '1.4.0'
```

Luckily `flink-streaming-java_2.11` library already had provided mentioned in `https://mvnrepository.com`

```
provided group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-streaming-java_2.11', version: '1.4.0'
```

Final **Module** `build.gradle` has these contents

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {

    packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'


    }


    configurations.all {

        // Enforces Gradle to only compile the version number you state for all dependencies, no matter which version number the dependencies have stated.

        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }


    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {

//        jackOptions { enabled true }

//        dexOptions { incremental true }

        multiDexEnabled true

        applicationId "com.example.amar.testing"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {

        customDebugType {
            debuggable true

        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


}

dependencies {

    // not sure if adding compatibility is required here
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7


    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

//    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
//        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
//    })


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // for multidex
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

    // for CEP
    provided group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-java', version: '1.4.0'
    provided group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-streaming-java_2.11', version: '1.4.0'


}
```

Final **Application** `build.gradle` has these contents

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {


        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3'

        apply plugin: 'java'
        apply plugin: 'eclipse'
        apply plugin: 'idea'


        sourceCompatibility = 1.7
        targetCompatibility = 1.7

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```